# "within 1 to 2 weeks" vs "in 1 or 2 weeks"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> 1.These symptoms  resolve  completely **within  1  to  2  weeks.**
>
> 2.These symptoms  resolve  completely  **in  1  or  2  weeks.**

I wanted to know whether the duration phrase "within 1 to 2 weeks" and " in 1 or 2 weeks" are the same.

Answer (score 3):

1. **“within a week”** would suggest that the symptoms should disappear *before* seven days, i.e. (very often) between three and five days
2. **“within one to two weeks**” suggests that the symptoms may last for up to a week, but not longer than two weeks
3. **“in one week”** suggests that the symptom will persist no longer than seven days
4. **“in one or two weeks”** suggests that the symptoms will persist for at least a  week but if not, they should clear up before the end of the second week.

It seems that medical websites and advertising for drugs, and medications prefer to use the term *within*, also note that the preposition **to** is often included.

> As harsh as the flu can be, the good news is that most people feel much better **within one to two weeks**. Most healthy adults become contagious the day before symptoms develop (which makes it trickier to prevent from spreading). They remain infectious for up to five to seven days after symptoms appear.
>   [source](http://vicks.com/en-us/treatments/how-to-treat-the-flu/how-long-does-the-flu-last)

- Flu symptoms usually start **within one to four days** after infection
- A bout of the flu typically **lasts one to two weeks**, with severe symptoms subsiding **in two to three** days
- The symptoms of flu usually develop within one to three days of becoming infected. Most people will feel better **within a week**.
- While cold symptoms can make you feel bad for a few days, flu symptoms can make you feel quite ill **for a few days to weeks**.