# It will be delivered to you 'with' or 'in' two days at the most

Tags: prepositions

> - It will be delivered to you **with** two days at the most.
> - It will be delivered to you **in** two days at the most.

which preposition is correct in the sentence?
Is it "with" or "in' after delivered

Comment: It should be "within" and not just "with".

Comment: Did you mean "within"? Related/duplicates: [in ten minutes vs within ten minutes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126609/in-ten-minutes-vs-within-ten-minutes); [“within 1 to 2 weeks” vs “in 1 or 2 weeks”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118343/within-1-to-2-weeks-vs-in-1-or-2-weeks).

Comment: i want to use either 'with' or 'in', so which one is more appropriate

Comment: If you're ruling out *within*, and unless you mean to use *with* in the sense of *something will be delivered **along with** two days (of something like free support)*, it should be *in*.